# FragmentTabHost add tab with image and textview

Tags: java, android, xml

I have one  `FragmentTabhost` XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:clickable="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/whte" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:background="@drawable/tabwidget"
        android:dividerPadding="0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:showDividers="middle" >
    </TabWidget>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/whte" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchcont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/search_background"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <FrameLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_text"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/searchedit"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="1dp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/serach_progress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:background="@color/footer_color" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_weight="0.65" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/bottom_currency"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.15"
                        android:src="@drawable/amd_icom" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/amount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Large Text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@color/whte"
                        android:textSize="32dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/setnewpin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/refill" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/newpincont"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.35"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/pinvalue"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:ems="10"
               android:hint="@string/pin_edit_hint_text"
               android:imeOptions="actionGo"
               android:inputType="number"
               android:maxLength="4"
               android:paddingBottom="1dp"
               android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               android:paddingTop="1dp" />

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/sendnewpin"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
               android:src="@drawable/submit_pin" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>
      </LinearLayout>

      </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

I added in FragmentTabhost 3 tabs:

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),getChildFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);
    Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
    arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(prepareTabView(getString(R.string.playlist), R.drawable.library_icon)),
            PlayListFragment.class, arg1);
    Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
    arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator(prepareTabView(getString(R.string.playlist), R.drawable.queue_icon)),
            PlayListFragment.class, arg2);

    Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
    arg3.putInt("Arg for Frag3", 3);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator(prepareTabView(getString(R.string.search), R.drawable.search_icon)),
    SearchFragment.class, arg3);
```

where `prepareTabView` medot for create tabs icon.
after this on 3 tabs only icon drawing ,text gone.

[image]

I want and icon and textview.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove the following from within fragmenttabhost?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Put it outside of the fragmenttabhost.